# Testing the convergence of difference of cube roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm studying for my exams and I came across some problems for which I can't find any kind of example:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n} $$

and then:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt[3]{n^2+1} - \sqrt[3]{n^2} $$

so obviously there is something I should learn to do here.
After that, there is the same problem but with the 5th root.

If someone could help me solve it I would be more than thankful.

Comment: Hint: telescoping series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**$$\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]n=\frac1{\sqrt[3]{n+1}^2+\sqrt[3]{n+1}\sqrt[3]n+\sqrt[3]n^2}.$$

Comment: Overkill!${}{}$

Comment: It may be overkill for the first sum, which is telescoping, but it is a good hint for the second sum, which does not telescope.

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, note that you have a telescoping sum, so you can write down explicitly the partial sums
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N \left(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]n\right)=\sqrt[3]{N+1}-\sqrt[3]{0}=\sqrt[3]{N+1}
$$
which $\to\infty$ as $N\to\infty$.

For the second sum, estimate
$$
\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{n^2}=\frac{(n^2+1)-n^2}{(\sqrt[3]{n^2+1})^2+\sqrt[3]{n^2}\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}+(\sqrt[3]{n^2})^2}\sim \frac1{3n^{4/3}}
$$
and so converges.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{n=0}^N \sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n}$ is just $\sqrt[3]{N+1}-\sqrt[3] 0$, because intermediate terms cancel. This tends to infinity, so the sum diverges.